# newbie help: if else Javascript statement that conditionally displays linked images

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, and need some direction on how to build this code.

I have 2 sets of 6-10 linked images (  )

First, I want the javascript code to select which set to display using an if else statement like below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    if (mmjsRegion == "CO")
       {
       document.write("<b>Colorado</b>");
       }
    else
       {
       document.write("<b>California</b>");
       }
    </script>
```

Then, I want the javascript code to randomly choose 3 linked images of the selected set, and display only those three.

How would the structure of this code look?

Any direction would help so much.

Thanks!
zeem

Comment: do you have any code to start?

Comment: nope, nothing yet. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: never have, but would love to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need two things: (1) a way to associate arbitrary image filenames with US states, and (2) a way to pick some random filenames from a set.

For (1) you could maintain a mapping of state abbreviation to related filenames, e.g.:

```
var stateImages = {
  'CO': ['img1-co.jpg', 'img2-co.jpg', 'img3-co.jpg'],
  'CA': ['img1-ca.jpg', 'img2-ca.jpg', 'img3-ca.jpg'] // etc.
};
var images = stateImages[mmjsRegion];
```

Then for (2) it should be easy to select random images from that list like so:

```
var selectedImages = [];
selectedImages.push(images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
selectedImages.push(images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
// now selectedImages has two random ones associated with the state.
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's definitely moving in the right direction.

how would I attach URLs to each image?

Comment: The image filenames could be entire URLs themselves.